# The size of test data does not fit into model (python)

Tags: python, neural-network

I have a problem with testing my model, when I train my model, it works well. However, when I try to put the test data into the model it gives the error of the size does not fit, which was expected for me. I have split my data into 70% training and 30% testing. I understand why is that so, yet couldn't solve it.

```
net = Net(n_feature=244, n_hidden=10, n_output=244)  
print(net)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.2)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()
```

There are also some code here.

```
def test():
Xtest = torch.FloatTensor(X_test)
ypred_test = net(Xtest)
plt.scatter(Xtest[:100] , y_test[:100])

plt.plot(Xtest.detach().numpy()[:100] , ypred_test.detach().numpy()[:100] , "red")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.show()
```

I am using jupyter notebook, thats why it is a bit messy. Any help would be great. Thanks in regard!
[Error can be seen from the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXy2C.png)

Comment: can you provide more detail about the size of data you are using for training and test

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the data has a size of (349,2). I used train_test_split to split the data into %30 test and %70 train. (244 data pair for training and 105 data pair for test) There are two features which are x and y. I am trying to build a neural network with pytorch to do regression. Then, I want to do hsic test for the causaliy. @AbhishekKumar